# ConflictRefiner not providing any output

Tags: python-2.7, docplex

I am working on a mixed integer linear optimization problem using docplex with python. On solving the problem, I get the problem status as INTEGER INFEASIBLE. The error reads as follows: Row 'Constraint1_358_36' infeasible, all entries at implied bounds. I tried the Conflict refiner module to identify the possible conflicts. However, conflict refiner appears to take infinite amount of time to produce results. What could be the possible causes for the same? Is there any other way to detect the cause of this infeasibility? The model details are as follows:

```
Model: ABCD
 - number of variables: 175200
   - binary=70080, integer=0, continuous=105120
 - number of constraints: 402964
   - linear=402964
 - parameters: defaults
CPXPARAM_Read_DataCheck                          1
Row 'Constraint1_358_36' infeasible, all entries at implied bounds.
Presolve time = 0.56 sec. (411.93 ticks)
```

The code for invoking conflict refiner is as follows:

```
conf = ConflictRefiner()                                   
conf.display_conflicts(conf.refine_conflict(model))
```